# Kaizen in DevOps methodology?

Tags: development-process, continuous-integration

I was wondering, Does anybody here works in a software development team under the DevOps methodology and applying Kaizen instead Lean for continuous improvement?

I read that DevOps is based on Agile methodology and Lean, but I don't know whether it's possible to use Kaizen instead Lean.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI http://teddziuba.com/2011/03/devops-scam.html and http://artige.com/k2l.htm - I don't see the point of DevOps, and I don't see a conflict between Kaizen and Lean

Comment: I don't see the point too (of devops). I was getting myself some culture with software development methodologies, project management, and quality, and I find with DevOps.

Answer (score 3):

[Kaizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen) (which is Japanese for "continuous improvement") is a concept inside of Lean, nothing something opposed or a substitute for Lean. Checkout a book called "[The Toyota Way](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071392319)". Is about manufacturing not software, but it will help you sort out the concepts about Lean Manufacturing.

The thing you should focus when thinking about Lean is elminating waste: [muda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muda_%28Japanese_term%29), [muri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muri_%28Japanese_term%29) and [mura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mura_%28Japanese_term%29).

People often refers to tools used in lean manufacturing as being lean. The most common tools is probably [kanban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban).

Regarding DevOps, I never saw it's point. It's, at least for me, just a fuzzy concept and a vacuous rebranding of existing ideas. Maybe I just don't get it.

There's a ton of books on the Toyota Production Systems and lean. Most relate to manufacturing but it's not really difficult to translate some concepts to software development. There's a few authors who talk a lot about Lean Software Development but I never really liked most of what I saw and I prefer the manufacturing books myself.

Comment: Kaizen actually means "improvement." Toyota and others (devops) used the term in a different context, eg, kaizen and the improvement kata. Since 2011, there is a great deal more on the topic in the devops movement.

Comment: @nicorellius That's a 5 years old answer. Why don't you write another one? I'll be glad to read (and upvote) it!

Comment: I was on my phone, and was pressed for time. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

[Kaizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen) actually generally means "improvement." Toyota and others (DevOps) used the term in a different context, eg, kaizen and the [improvement kata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota_Kata). I'd suggest a couple books that have really shaped the DevOps movement (and that talk about this concept in detail):

http://itrevolution.com/books/

**Phoenix Project** (one of my favorites) and the **DevOps Handbook** (a fabulous integration of concepts and real life examples).

I also recommend Jennifer Davis and Katherine Daniels' book, **Effective DevOps**:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920039846.do

And don't forget **The Goal** by  Eliyahu Goldratt:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goal_%28novel%29

The idea of improvement in DevOps is that it is equally, if not more, important to spend a portion of your time improving your systems than just doing work. We have all been in the situation where a process isn't automated, but yet we still push forward doing it the hard way, because "we don't have time" to do it right. Well, we should spend (maybe 25%) of our time actually improving our workflow so these bad habits go away.